# How to inner join in mongodb. (aggregation)

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

What i want to do is find out which **post** i have reacted to and return true or false as below result i expect.  i know about ***aggregation*** in mongodb but i don't know how it works yet.  If anyone has study material about it, please comment.  thank you.

```js
// user model
{
    "_id": "62d0d2e8306367e5162b9c4e",
    "fullname": "string",
    "username": "string",
    "avatar": "string",
    "bio": "string",
    "tick": true,
    "followings_count": 55,
    "followers_count": 5,
    "likes_count": 0,
    "website_url": "",
    "social_network": [],
    "created_at": "2022-07-15T02:37:28.565Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-08-23T08:23:16.611Z",
    "__v": 0
}

// post model
{
    "_id": "62f0ad6cca2731b7a851b5a5",
    "contents": ":>>",
    "media_url": "string",
    "reaction_count": 1,
    "view_count": 0,
    "category_id": [],
    "created_at": "2022-08-08T06:30:04.137Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-08-24T04:10:33.944Z",
    "__v": 0,
    "comment_count": 9
}

// post_reaction model
{
    "user_id": "62d0d2e8306367e5162b9c4e",
    "post_id":"62f0ad6cca2731b7a851b5a5",
    "type": "Like",
}
```

This is the result i expect:

```js
{
    "data": {
        "user": {
            "_id": "62d0d2e8306367e5162b9c4e",
            ...
        },
        "post": [
            {
                "_id": "62f0ad6cca2731b7a851b5a5",
                ...
                "is_reaction": true(false)),
            },
            ...
        ]
}
```

Comment: You can refer this: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/

Answer (score 0):

I found the way resolve this issues:

```js
const result = await PostModel.aggregate([
        {
          $match: { user_id: ObjectUserId },
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: 'post_reaction',
            localField: '_id',
            foreignField: 'post_id',
            as: 'isReaction',
          },
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 1,
            contents: 1,
            media_url: 1,
            reaction_count: 1,
            view_count: 1,
            category_id: 1,
            created_at: 1,
            updated_at: 1,
            comment_count: 1,
            isReaction: {
              $filter: {
                input: '$isReaction',
                cond: {
                  $eq: ['$$this.user_id', ObjectUserId],
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
        { $sort: { _id: -1 } },
      ]);
```